# How to enable session resumption on tlsv1.3 by netty server side

Tags: netty, tls1.3

I hava a java netty server like this:

```
public class Server {

    public Server(int port) {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
        EventLoopGroup workGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(2);
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(bossGroup,workGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel sc) throws Exception {
                        sc.pipeline().addFirst(sslInit().newHandler(sc.alloc()));
                    }
                });
        try {
            ChannelFuture cf  = bootstrap.bind(port).sync();
            cf.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
    private SslContext sslInit() throws Exception {
        SslContext sslContext = null;
        String basePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator ;
        File chain = new File(basePath + "/cert/client-chain.cer");
        File serverKeyContent = new File(basePath + "/cert/server.key");
        File serverCrtContent = new File(basePath + "/cert/server.cer");
        sslContext = SslContextBuilder
                .forServer(serverCrtContent, serverKeyContent)
                .trustManager(chain)
                .clientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRE)
                .protocols("TLSv1.3")
                .sessionTimeout(60)
                .sessionCacheSize(1000)
                .sslProvider(SslProvider.OPENSSL_REFCNT)
                .enableOcsp(true)
                .build();
        ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext context = (ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext) sslContext;
        Field ctx = ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.class.getDeclaredField("ctx");
        ctx.setAccessible(true);
        long num = ctx.getLong(context);
        boolean result = SSLContext.setNumTickets(num,1);
        return sslContext;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.setProperty("jdk.tls.server.enableSessionTicketExtension","true");
        new Server(4443);
    }
}
```

When I use openssl command to connect it but no sessionTicket return.

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:4443 -CAfile client-chain.cer -key client.key.pem -cert client.cert.pem
CONNECTED(00000260)
Can't use SSL_get_servername
depth=2 C = cn, ST = ln, L = sy, O = neu, OU = neu, CN = neu
verify return:1
depth=1 C = cn, ST = ln, O = neu, OU = neu, CN = neu
verify return:1
depth=0 C = cn, ST = ln, L = sy, O = neu, OU = neu, CN = neu
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = cn, ST = ln, L = sy, O = neu, OU = neu, CN = neu
   i:C = cn, ST = ln, O = neu, OU = neu, CN = neu
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFKjCCAxKgAwIBAgICEAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwRDELMAkGA1UEBhMCY24x
CzAJBgNVBAgMAmxuMQwwCgYDVQQKDANuZXUxDDAKBgNVBAsMA25ldTEMMAoGA1UE
AwwDbmV1MB4XDTIzMDYwNTAxMDk0M1oXDTI0MDYxNDAxMDk0M1owUTELMAkGA1UE
BhMCY24xCzAJBgNVBAgMAmxuMQswCQYDVQQHDAJzeTEMMAoGA1UECgwDbmV1MQww
CgYDVQQLDANuZXUxDDAKBgNVBAMMA25ldTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEP
ADCCAQoCggEBAL3OIsL763H1dNCxkUWhI6O/SISRIDwla39P31AYCNPeK/W6qkjn
991o9bHyg6uRgpbmoHbJUW1hdPPQjHe/7VUTIBfh3IMv4/cLjtAlWTlq0WYGPgUB
ScWYozPIt1GTJtP44lx0UZqUXGgtRR5JG+JkfsVdfhUTn2GmKzTobrIIaBB3BC+x
ZRg+2lV5lXE7QOHu/i00EtJCpsUcLJLi1COCeyQROOlvTcBhOPJsdOxZvnzBhIV3
tD5GHwo3Me2VQ032IsIpeMY3FGC6HAcmfvPMOKVhHPK4/Hi6LyK+7H+HWZjtpqeE
kY4h8+k0St0rhuh6ERhKL7mZT+HREFKNneUCAwEAAaOCARcwggETMAkGA1UdEwQC
MAAwEQYJYIZIAYb4QgEBBAQDAgZAMDMGCWCGSAGG+EIBDQQmFiRPcGVuU1NMIEdl
bmVyYXRlZCBTZXJ2ZXIgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUwHQYDVR0OBBYEFNosRpLgBYBCixW2
D/AvKZ9Dnwc1MHoGA1UdIwRzMHGAFCmFqUCkP9lhSRdQ7x7TLxBP5LifoVWkUzBR
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJjbjELMAkGA1UECAwCbG4xCzAJBgNVBAcMAnN5MQwwCgYDVQQK
DANuZXUxDDAKBgNVBAsMA25ldTEMMAoGA1UEAwwDbmV1ggIQADAOBgNVHQ8BAf8E
BAMCBaAwEwYDVR0lBAwwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggIBACcT
oZIrvBRWBLbYVIs0scOfyhgb7WqHteKGX0GoLqNp5owxHeVg875zn4DiA4lj/+a5
sQgE1zbp1U7f1H+jVnX31g5k9+sU7vqQ848f38ofVb5/nwST/NmNsJlR7Pd8XYAs
XomS0f0n3Lds5ihQTMRSlzvFrLPTMRAPyI71AB4trJVVh9IXTpuz/u5bNfsFFdkm
pjf2HGniY0vCw3ugBGcQyXFhdhEnmbeM9NJZNq6OJgeYQ4oCKGYhaQSTVwfP54oe
0715/xCUMXCXy2ZcTrsuER78AmJS7yg9IHJM2noRx/ZwPGtPI+ZCexvd5KFpUS3P
4R892SxvMlivEBFH83M1wdrHq3vyk9yzqT7l2ElHdygLAA5W7YqjidwPYLlUhuko
Y7+hQNQCydH71w5uSaSKO4vwey8b0QEYEHYbh2AHq9kmF5p12uBuEbc5YtYsbIU+
G0BF4OklPS6AhAuxJE7IEr6Px6rVUU6Eg4JGaKM9asencBKMFGHlKbpJYK428Sna
nzMxvi9Ft1c8WT/WBbQx5c5FuTDxcVn5DwFieleOXu2n+XYc4+Tm5YIGqnFdTnLW
DVyoyfowclTBtV0QYvGzlSFdT18nEkUYBXE4sMNESW0EUXg/6ody1amVclXeC/Cl
hSxbj6Zd/mHFWNr9emAeo8sCeZjA4KLvDW795hLg
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = cn, ST = ln, L = sy, O = neu, OU = neu, CN = neu

issuer=C = cn, ST = ln, O = neu, OU = neu, CN = neu

---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
C = cn, ST = ln, O = neu, OU = neu, CN = neu
C = cn, ST = ln, L = sy, O = neu, OU = neu, CN = neu
Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA1
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA512
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2010 bytes and written 4828 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
```

Any ideas about how to config netty server return sessionTicket after handshark success.

soft verison:
OpenSSL 1.1.1v
java 1.8
pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SEVER</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <version>4.1.54.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.50.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any ideas about how to config netty server return sessionTicket after handshark success.